# solving nonlinear ode - $y'+y^2=4x, y(0)=0, y(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to specific solution of $y'+y^2=4x, y(0)=0, y(1)=0$.
since it is nonlinear and inhomogeneous, some tactics for linear ODEs - didn't work.
also, I think it is not possible to bring new function $v = 4x-y^2$ too.
which would be a good way to solve this problem?
any help would be grateful.

Comment: What techniques for solving ODEs do you know? Also, what makes you think the differential equation has a closed form solution?

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+y^2=4x, y(0)=0, y(1)=0$$
This is Riccati's differential equation. Substitute $y=\dfrac {u'}u$:
$$\dfrac {u''u-u'^2}{u^2}+\dfrac {u'^2}{u^2}=4x$$
$$u''-4xu=0$$
This is [Airy differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) . You can try series solution method.